# Visual Studio 2015 indentation behavior for files with different indent size

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, auto-indent

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 (RTM) with installed extension Productivity Power Tools 2015.

My indentation settings for C# are smart indenting, tab + indent size 4, insert spaces. I have auto-format enabled on closing braces, semicolons and paste.

However, in my project I have lots of old code files which were created using indentation (space) size of 2.

```
namespace Foo
{
  public class Bar
  {
    public void Method()
    {
    }
  }
}
```

Using above example, in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, when adding code to `Method`, it would detect that indentation for `Method` is 6 spaces, and would there add 4 spaces for the body when writing code.

Likewise when adding a new method to the class, it would fix up the indentation when closing the brace, so that it is aligned correctly with the other methods.

```
namespace Foo
{
  public class Bar
  {
    public void Method()
    {
        // New line starts here
    }

    public void NewlyAdded()
    {
    } // Typing this fixes intendation
  }
}
```

Now in VS 2015, this behavior is gone. It uses strictly the space size defined in the settings. So when I write code in the method body, it inserts 3*4 = 12 spaces. It also doesn't align the method when typing the closing brace like in VS 2013.

```
namespace Foo
{
  public class Bar
  {
    public void Method()
    {
            // New line starts here   
    }

        public void NewlyAdded()
        {
        } // Typing closing brace doesn't align
  }
}
```

What's worse, pasting code or using refactoring partly formats surrounding code, messing up the indentation completely. In even deeper nested blocks it really gets annoying, having to fix up indentation so that the code remains readable.

I want to avoid having to format the whole document and checking those changes in to version control, just to be able to modify code without having indentation issues while writing.

Is this a bug, or am I missing an extension or a setting in VS 2015?

Comment: @CodeCaster It's under "Text Editor"->"C#"->"Formatting" in VS.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the same question in a related GitHub issue of the dotnet/roslyn project.
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4351

Although the issue is still open as of today, the outcome of the discussion is that Microsoft does not want to support mixed indentations inside a single file in roslyn.

Part of Microsoft's answer to this as stated in the GitHub issue are the new .editorconfig files: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/11/28/productivity-in-visual-studio-2017-rc/

Due to this, I went and reformatted all legacy code files according to my updated code style, and checked that into version control. That way, there are no indentation issues, and git blame can ignore those whitespace changes.